# How can I force log4net to respect the current culture in the date pattern?

Tags: c#, logging, log4net, globalization

I am running a console application on a machine where the culture is set to German. I want to include the date and time in all messages of the log file and therefore I am using the string formatter 'G'.
When I use Console.WriteLine to write the current date to the console it is formatted in German as expected.
Why is the date of log4net formatted in US culture instead and how can I change it so that it respects the local culture?

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using log4net;
using log4net.Config;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var repo = LogManager.CreateRepository(
                Assembly.GetEntryAssembly(), typeof(log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy));

            XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(repo, new FileInfo("log4net.config"));

            var logger = LogManager.GetLogger(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly(), "Program");

            logger.Info("Hello World!");
            Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:G} Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

**log4net.config**

```
<log4net>

  <root>
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
  </root>

  <appender name="console" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date{G} %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

</log4net>
```

**Console Output**

```
08/24/2020 13:20:19 Hello World!
24.08.2020 13:20:19 Hello World!
```

Comment: I am not aware of a method to make it respect the culture. You can give it the german format explicitly. But actually, I wouldn't recommend that. I'd always prefer ISO8601 (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss) in logfiles.